# mouseover on image changes text link color

Tags: css, image, text, hover, hyperlink

basically i've 6 pictures with 6 text links down to them

i've done css hovering on pictures (color version -> on hover -> black & white version)

and on text links (black font -> on hover -> red font)

when i'm hovering on links - picture is getting hovered version (B&W) and that's ok, but that's only working in this direction, in opposite direction when i'm hovering on picture - text link stays the same (black font)

and that's my question, how to connect this two elements (text links and pictures)?

here's my code:

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">     
li class="element_1"><a href="./first_link.html"></a>
<a href="./first_link.html" class="text">Text of the<br>First<br>Link</a></li>

[rest of the elements list]
</ul>
```

CSS

```
 ul.menu element_1{
 width:130px;
 margin-left:20px;
  height:130px;
 display: block; background: url(img/menu_1.jpg) top center no-repeat;;
}


ul.menu li.element_1:hover{
 width:130px;
 margin-left:20px;

 display: block; background: url(img/menu_1_bw.jpg) top center no-repeat;;
```

Answer (score 0):

Particularly as you're making use of background images, I would recommend restructuring your HTML to use only a single anchor. Then, when hovering that, you can apply both your image  and font colour change.

Take a look [at the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/cV8uh/) for a simple example*. Here's the new CSS:

```
.element_1 a {
    width:130px;
    margin-left:20px;
    height:130px;
    display: block; 
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/200/300') top center no-repeat;
    color: red;
}

.element_1 a:hover{
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/300/300');
    color: green;
}
```

When defining your `:hover` state, you only need to specify those things that are changing, rather than re-stating everything.

* Note that your HTML/CSS needed tidying up. You missed the `.` for your class selector and had multiple semi-colons. Make sure that your code validates and doesn't have these simple mistakes, as they will mask the true problem.

Comment: thank you for quick reply, the problem is the code was not written by me and is messy - i know this :) but... your example [link]http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/cV8uh/[/link] is about situation when text is ON the picture and I want to make this: picture on top / space left on bottom / text link

Comment: You should find that easy to amend using CSS alone. Check out the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/cV8uh/) for an example of the layout you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any CSS for changing the link color.  I guess you're counting on the browser to do it?

You can fix this by adding the rule to your existing CSS:

```
ul.menu li.element_1:hover{
 color: red;

 width:130px;
 margin-left:20px;

 display: block; background: url(img/menu_1_bw.jpg) top center no-repeat;
}
```

The alternative is to put your image and text inside a single  element, in which case the browser will apply its automatic link highlight to the whole element.